# Unaligned address in store

Tags: assembly, storage, mips, qtspim

I have this code and it tells me i have unaligned address in store when saving a double . Can someone please tell me what is happening?? Specifically i am getting the error message in the first sdc1 when i'm putting in the first value for A(1,1). Could the problem be from the rest of the program>? The error messages say exception occurred at PC=0x0040003c, Unaligned address in store: 0x1001009b and attempt to execute non-instruction at 0x80000180. I am using qtspim

```
.data
user_prompt: .asciiz "Please enter a values for: \n"
a11:  .asciiz "A(1,1)= "
a12:  .asciiz "A(1,2)= "
a21:  .asciiz "A(2,1)= "
a22:  .asciiz "A(2,2)= "
b11:  .asciiz "B(1,1)= "
b12:  .asciiz "B(1,2)= "
b21:  .asciiz "B(2,1)= "
b22:  .asciiz "B(2,2)= "
c11:  .asciiz "C(1,1)=       "
c12:  .asciiz "C(1,2)= /n"
c21:  .asciiz "C(2,1)=       "
c22:  .asciiz "C(2,2)= "

A:  .space 32
B:  .space 32
C:  .space 32


#Text section
.text
.globl main

main:


la $a1, A
la $a2, B
la $a3, C


li $v0, 4
la $a0, user_prompt
syscall

#Ask for A(1,1)
li  $v0 , 4

la  $a0 , a11       

syscall

#Read double
li  $v0 , 7

syscall

#Store double
sdc1    $f0 , ($a1)



li  $v0 , 4

la  $a0 , a12       

syscall

li  $v0 , 7

syscall

sdc1    $f0 , 8($a1)



#Same for the rest
li  $v0 , 4

la  $a0 , a21 

syscall

li  $v0 , 7

syscall

sdc1    $f0 , 16($a1)



li  $v0 , 4

la  $a0 , a22       

syscall

li  $v0 , 7

syscall

sdc1    $f0 , 24($a1)



#Same for array B
li  $v0 , 4

la  $a0 , b11 
syscall

li  $v0 , 7

syscall

sdc1    $f0 , 0($a2)    



li  $v0 , 4

la  $a0 , b12
 syscall

li  $v0 , 7

syscall

sdc1    $f0 , 8($a2)




li  $v0 , 4

la  $a0 , b21       

    syscall

li  $v0 , 7

syscall

sdc1    
$f0 , 16($a2)



li  $v0 , 4

la  $a0 , b22        

syscall

li  $v0 , 7

syscall

sdc1    $f0 , 24($a2)



#initializing indexes i,j,k
addi $s0, $zero, 0
addi $s1, $zero, 0
addi $s2, $zero, 0

li $t8, 3 #initializing length +1



addi $sp, $sp, -16
sw $s0, 0($sp)
sw $s1, 4($sp)
sw $s2, 8($sp)


while1:
beq $s0,$t8,exit1
sw $ra, 12($sp)
jal while2
addi $s0,$s0,1
j while1

while2:
sw $ra, 12($sp)
beq $s1,$t8,exit2
addi $s1,$s1,1
jal while3 
addi $s1,$s1,1
j while2


while3:
beq $s2,$t8,exit3
mul $t0,$s0,2

add $t1,$t0,$s1
sll $t2,$t1,3
add $t3,$t2,$a1
add $t4,$t2,$a2
add $t5,$t2,$a3
ldc1 $f4, ($t3)
ldc1 $f6, ($t4)
ldc1 $f8, ($t5)
mul.d $f8,$f6,$f4
sdc1 $f8, ($t5)
addi $s2,$s2,1
j while3


exit1:
lw $s0, 0($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 16
jr $ra

exit2:
lw $s1, 4($sp)
jr $ra

exit3:
lw $s1, 8($sp)
jr while


#Printing results
li  $v0, 4                  
la  $a0, c11
syscall 
ldc1    $f12, ($a2)         
li  $v0, 3
syscall

li  $v0, 4                  
la  $a0, c12
syscall 
ldc1    $f12, 8($a2)            
li  $v0, 3
syscall

li  $v0, 4                  
la  $a0, c21
syscall 
ldc1    $f12, 16($a2)           
li  $v0, 3
syscall

li  $v0, 4                  
la  $a0, c22
syscall 
ldc1    $f12, 24($a2)           
li  $v0, 3
syscall

#Ending program
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: What is the alignment of `A:` after all those strings? You could use a `.align` directive to select the proper alignment.

Comment: so do i have to add an .align 3 instruction? for 8 bytes ?

Comment: yes, ahead of `A:  .space 32` ... wasn't my answer to previous question clear enough? If not, you should ask about things which are confusing you. BTW, `.align 3` is not instruction, but assembler directive. It will not translate into some CPU instruction, it will only affect the way how the assembler will translate the rest of the source. Anything starting with dot in qtspim assembly is directive of assembler, not instruction. And if qtspim does produce listing after compilation, check how the align will change resulting address of `A` (or check the `A` symbol in debugger).